# REGEX (python) match or return a string after '?', but in a new line, til the end of that line

Tags: python, regex

Here us what I'm trying to do... I have a string structured like this:

stringparts.bst? (carriage return)
765945559287eghc1bg60aa26e4c9ccf8ac425725622f65a6lsa6ahskchksyttsutcuan99 (carriage return)
SPAM /198975/

I need it to match or return this:

765945559287eghc1bg60aa26e4c9ccf8ac425725622f65a6lsa6ahskchksyttsutcuan99

What RegEx will do the trick?

I have tried this, but to no avail :(

bst\?(.*)\n

Thanks in advc

Comment: \s can be use to indicate a whitespace. Try bst\?\s(.+)\s

Comment: `\n` is a newline/linefeed, not a carriage return (that's `\r`).

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work (almost)...I've tested on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html and it returns:765945559287eghc1bg60aa26e4c9ccf8ac425725622f65a6lsa6ahskchksyttsutcuan99\r (extra \r) not needed :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried this. Assuming the newline is only one character.

```
>>> s
'stringparts.bst?\n765945559287eghc1bg60aa26e4c9ccf8ac425725622f65a6lsa6ahskchks
yttsutcuan99\nSPAM /198975/'
>>> m = re.match('.*bst\?\s(.+)\s', s)
>>> print m.group(1)
765945559287eghc1bg60aa26e4c9ccf8ac425725622f65a6lsa6ahskchksyttsutcuan99
```

Comment: Thanks Bro! Strange! regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html is not returning the same!!! see: http://ge.tt/79W2EJf/v/0?c

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will match everything between the `bst?` and the first newline which is nothing.  I think you want to match everything between the first two newlines.

```
bst\?\n(.*)\n
```

will work, but you could also use

```
\n(.*)\n
```

although it may not work for some other more specific cases

Answer (score 0):

This is more robust against different kinds of line breaks, and works if you have a whole list of such strings. The `$` and `^` represent the beginning and end of a line, but not the actual line break character (hence the `\s+` sequence).

```
import re

BST_RE = re.compile(
    r"bst\?.*$\s+^(.*)$",
    re.MULTILINE
)

INPUT_STR = r"""
stringparts.bst?
765945559287eghc1bg60aa26e4c9ccf8ac425725622f65a6lsa6ahskchksyttsutcuan99
SPAM /198975/

stringparts.bst?
another
SPAM /.../
"""

occurrences = BST_RE.findall(INPUT_STR)

for occurrence in occurrences:
    print occurrence
```

Comment: I tried this ( .*stringparts.bst?\?(.*)[a-z][0-9] ) and while it returns the correct string.  it somehow truncates it so it's missing a few digit/characters..please tell me what I'm doing wrong? THX INPUT: stringparts.bst?765945559287eghc1bg60aa26e4c9ccf8ac425725622f65a6lsa6ahskchksyttsutcuan99jjgjaa6879797979a7a7xa9x7a9c7s9cs79cs7c97ca97ca9c7a9c7ahahiahxaihai778aa8aa0809768b   THIS TIME I PUT THE FULL STRING.

Comment: If you want to restrict the character range, use this: `r"bst\?.*$\s+^.*?([a-z0-9]*).*?$","`. The `.*?` sequences mean "match whatever you can (like `.*`), but in the shortest possible way." It's called a *non-greedy match*.

Comment: Thank you guys! I appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

This pattern allows additional whitespace before the `\n`:

```
r'bst\?\s*\n(.*?)\s*\n'
```

If you don't expect any whitespace within the string to be captured, you could use a simpler one, where `\s+` consumes whitespace, including the `\n`, and `(\S+)` captures all the consecutive non-whitespace:

```
r'bst\?\s+(\S+)'
```